# Moving the title of a link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am not a HTML/CSS expert but I am in charge of developing and maintaining a website for my employer.

I have set of link in the middle of my webpage that I want to have a specific CSS applied to without affecting any of the other links, and really the only change I want to make is to move the title popup to the right. Basically, the *pointing hand* hover mouse icon blocks the text in the title, so I want to move the popup to the right of the pointer, so that it can be read completely during a hover.

I've seen a few different ways to manipulate the title popup but they are either way too complex for what I need, way too simple in that they affect all `<a>` tags on the page, or do not explain how to do what I want which is just move the popup to the right a little bit.

Comment: Is the popup in the HTML/CSS/JS? Or is it generated by the browser from the title or href?

Comment: We still do not know which title you are trying to move. Is it an HTML element or just the way the browser shows links when you hover?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Having done further research on this, I found several questions in StackExchange that indicate that a title cannot be modified. So given this:

```
<a title='stuff here' href='#'>Click me!</a>
```

it is not possible to manipulate the "stuff here" section using jscript, css, etc. The only option is to use a jQuery plugin or something along those lines, and that has proven to be beyond my ability to troubleshoot.

For the time being, I simply added spaces to the front of the title to push the text out, like this:

```
<a title='     stuff here' href='#'>Click me!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually style any element of the page by using 'inline styling' which will not effect any of the other elements on the page.

You do this in the HTML rather than the Style sheet, for example say your style sheet has:

```
.tinybutton {margin:0;padding;0:}
```

Which would use the element in HTML as:

```
<a class="tinybutton" href="#"> </a>
```

Now let's pretend you want to move the button slightly right without editing the CSS you then use the inline styling like so:

```
<a class="tinybutton" style="margin-left:10px" href="#"> </a>
```

So in other words just add `style=" "` with the styling options you require to the element that you want to edit without effecting the CSS.

Comment: Ok, that explains the concept of inline styling, but how do I move the title? The above code repositions the link itself. I need the title repositioned.

Comment: You need to provide more information, such as the HTML code of the element that you want to adjust.. the URL wouldn't go a miss either.

Answer (score 0):

*Now that you have answered your own question, I know that the titles you are trying to move are tool-tips generated by the browser.*

Not only can those not be moved, **these tooltips are browser dependent and looks different on each browser**. I have no idea which one you are  using  but it is *not* Chrome because we made sure that the tooltip does not overlap the mouse cursor.

The other possibility, like the jQuery plugin you mentioned, is to write Javascript that renders each title in its own invisible HTML element. Then it makes those tooltips appear on by adding an a :hover style or mouse-event-handler.